# php soap client with a local wsdl call

Tags: php, url, soap, soap-client

I´m a newbie to soap in php, so I apologize if I´m not precise in my description.

I have working soap clients consuming wsdl´s in a providers remote server (eg `www.remoteaddress.com/wsdl/webservice.wsdl`). I was wondering if I could speed up that first wsdl call (before getting it into de cache) by downloading that wsdl from the remote server and uploading it locally to the same folder that contains the php that makes the call.

php.net says...

```
$client = new SoapClient(null, array('location' => "http://localhost/soap.php",
                                     'uri'      => "http://test-uri/",
                                     'style'    => SOAP_DOCUMENT,
                                     'use'      => SOAP_LITERAL));
```

So, questions please...does the location always have to be an http address or can a local apache server address be used (so as to reference a folder on a higher level than the public_html)? or in other words how do I reference in "location" the folder containing the the local uploaded wsdl? Would this speed things up, and if the local wsdl is in a public directory in my local server, does that pose some sort of security risk? Tried some combinations with the localhost above but none worked...

Thanks in advance for your help,
Pablo